# want scrolling div boxs along with scrolling images behind

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want something like this, some scrolling white small div boxes floating along with the image behind:
http://www.myprovence.fr/snapshots2012/fr/marseille-provence/0-carte.html

I am using "Smooth Div Scroll" plugin, could not make those scrolling white small div boxes.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>I Love Kolkata</title>

    <!-- the CSS for Smooth Div Scroll -->
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/smoothDivScroll.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <!-- Styles for my specific scrolling content -->
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body {height: 100%; min-height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;} /* Added by Souvik */

        #makeMeScrollable
        {
            width:100%;
            /*height: 330px;*/
            height: 100%;   /*Added by souvik */
            min-height:100%;
            position: relative;
        }

        /* Replace the last selector for the type of element you have in
           your scroller. If you have div's use #makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea div,
           if you have links use #makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea a and so on. */
        #makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea img
        {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
            /*height:1200px;*/
        }


    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="makeMeScrollable">
        <img src="images/test/map_slice_1.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="field" />
        <img src="images/test/map_slice_2.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="gnome" />
        <img src="images/test/map_slice_3.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="pencils" />
        <img src="images/test/map_slice_4.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="golf" />
        <img src="images/test/map_slice_5.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="river" />
        <img src="images/test/map_slice_6.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="train" />
        <img src="images/test/map_slice_7.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="leaf" />
        <img src="images/test/map_slice_8.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="dog" />
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery library - Please load it from Google API's -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery UI (Custom Download containing only Widget and Effects Core)
         You can make your own at: http://jqueryui.com/download -->
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Latest version (3.1.4) of jQuery Mouse Wheel by Brandon Aaron
         You will find it here: https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel -->
    <script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- jQuery Kinectic (1.8.2) used for touch scrolling -->
    <!-- https://github.com/davetayls/jquery.kinetic/ -->
    <script src="js/jquery.kinetic.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Smooth Div Scroll 1.3 minified-->
    <script src="js/jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.3-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- If you want to look at the uncompressed version you find it at
         js/jquery.smoothDivScroll-1.3.js -->

    <!-- Plugin initialization -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Initialize the plugin with no custom options
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // None of the options are set
            $("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
                hotSpotScrolling: false,
                touchScrolling: true,
                manualContinuousScrolling: true,
                mousewheelScrolling: false,
                mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
                hotSpotScrolling: true
            });

            var $windowheight = $(window).height();
            //alert($windowheight);
            $("#makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea img").css('height',$windowheight);

            $(window).resize(function() {
              $("#makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea img" ).css('height',$windowheight);
            });

        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/* You can alter this CSS in order to give Smooth Div Scroll your own look'n'feel */

/* Invisible left hotspot */
div.scrollingHotSpotLeft
{
    /* The hotspots have a minimum width of 100 pixels and if there is room the will grow
    and occupy 15% of the scrollable area (30% combined). Adjust it to your own taste. */
    min-width: 75px;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    /* There is a big background image and it's used to solve some problems I experienced
    in Internet Explorer 6. */
    background-image: url(../images/big_transparent.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 200;
    left: 0;
    /*  The first url is for Firefox and other browsers, the second is for Internet Explorer */
    cursor: url(../images/cursors/cursor_arrow_left.png), url(../images/cursors/cursor_arrow_left.cur),w-resize;
}

/* Visible left hotspot */
div.scrollingHotSpotLeftVisible
{
    background-image: url(../images/arrow_left.gif);                
    background-color: #fff;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.35; /* Standard CSS3 opacity setting */
    -moz-opacity: 0.35; /* Opacity for really old versions of Mozilla Firefox (0.9 or older) */
    filter: alpha(opacity = 35); /* Opacity for Internet Explorer. */
    zoom: 1; /* Trigger "hasLayout" in Internet Explorer 6 or older versions */
}

/* Invisible right hotspot */
div.scrollingHotSpotRight
{
    min-width: 75px;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../images/big_transparent.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 200;
    right: 0;
    cursor: url(../images/cursors/cursor_arrow_right.png), url(../images/cursors/cursor_arrow_right.cur),e-resize;
}

/* Visible right hotspot */
div.scrollingHotSpotRightVisible
{
    background-image: url(../images/arrow_right.gif);
    background-color: #fff;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.35;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 35);
    -moz-opacity: 0.35;
    zoom: 1;
}

/* The scroll wrapper is always the same width and height as the containing element (div).
   Overflow is hidden because you don't want to show all of the scrollable area.
*/
div.scrollWrapper
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div.scrollableArea
{
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```